# trouble calling a viewmodel from a viewmodel within a ko.computed statement

Tags: c#, javascript, knockout.js

I am not sure if this is possible or not but i have two view model functions in my javascript and within one i reference the other but i am getting an error. Here are my view models:

```
var userViewModel = function (data) {
        var _self = this;
        _self.ID = ko.observable(data.ID);
        _self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        //_self.ShowLetter = ko.computed(function () {
        //    return (typeViewModel().UserCount() > 13);
        //});
        _self.Letter = ko.observable(data.Letter);
    };
```

second view model:

```
var typeViewModel = function (data) {
        var _self = this;
        _self.ContentType = ko.observable(data.ContentType);
        _self.TypeName = ko.observable(data.TypeName);
        _self.UserCount = ko.observable(data.UserCount);
        _self.Users = ko.observableArray([]);
    };
```

when i uncomment the lines in the first viewModel and then run the app - in the console i am getting an error stating it cannot find the property for ContentType.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ()

See this Q&A for why - [Setting value of Observable not updating in Knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391415/setting-value-of-observable-not-updating-in-knockout)

Your view model is not an observable, so you don't need to 'get' the value.

Comment: This helped and removed the error but now i am binding it `data-binding="visible:ShowLetter, text:Letter"` and it seems like it is not doing what it should do. It is showing the letter for all users even if the count is under 13 - similar to my previous post

Comment: Can't help you write your app man, you need to console.log(typeViewModel.UserCount()) and see what the value is...