# How to use ko.observableArray?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have written simple example to learn about how ko.observableArray works.

```
**HTML**:
Count is : <span data-bind="text anotherObservableArray().length"> </span>

JS:
var anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray( [
{ name: "A", type: "A" },
{ name: "B", type: "B" },
{ name: "C", type: "C" }
]);

ko.applyBindings(anotherObservableArray);
```

Here is the link for the example am trying to implement

http://jsfiddle.net/Rama_Kishore/ZPDBv/

I was expecting "Count is: 3" output ,instead it's the output is "Count is:"

Please let me know why the count is not getting displayed.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting value of Observable not updating in Knockout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391415/setting-value-of-observable-not-updating-in-knockout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ko.observableArray` should be a part of `model` object.
E.g.

```
var viewModel = new function()
{
   this.anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray(...);
}
```

or

```
var viewModel = {
   anotherObservableArray : ko.observableArray(...);
}
```

Apply bindings

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yk4Ty/)

You can find very good [knockout online-tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) here

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working fork of your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/myjkk/2/

Note how the **[text binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html)** syntax includes a colon:

```
<span data-bind="text: anotherObservableArray().length"></span>
```

Note in the javascript how `ko.applyBindings` is used. See the knockout documentation 
for Activating Knockout: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

```
var vm = {
    anotherObservableArray: ko.observableArray([{
        name: "A",
        type: "A"
    }, {
        name: "B",
        type: "B"
    }, {
        name: "C",
        type: "C"
    }])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Also worth noting is that n your original fiddle, you did **not** include the knockoutjs library.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues:

- You didnt include Knockout as a library in js fiddle
- You didn't provide a vm object that wraps your observable array
- You had a typo in the binding

Fiddle : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPDBv/6/)

```
var vm = {
    anotherObservableArray : ko.observableArray( [
       { name: "A", type: "A" },
       { name: "B", type: "B" },
       { name: "C", type: "C" }
    ])
}
 ko.applyBindings(vm);
```