# Convert or Map Knockout array to an object

Tags: knockout.js

I have a Knockout observable array with the internal structure shown below,

```
property: "Email"
value: "name@email.com"
```

I would need to convert it into a knockout Model object like this,

```
var obj;
obj.Email ="name@email.com";
```

Is there a simplistic way to achieve this in Knockout?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting value of Observable not updating in Knockout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391415/setting-value-of-observable-not-updating-in-knockout)

Comment: i am afraid it is not

Comment: Sure it is, you aren't asking a unique question, maybe you just don't realize that yet because you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: can you please post rest of your code and what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a re-usable model to use in your view models. This is similar to using a class in C# to create objects that have common properties.

```
function objectModel(item) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(item.name);
    self.Description = ko.observable(item.description);
}
```

Which can be invoked like -

```
var object = {
    name: 'John',
    description: 'a person'
}

var john = new objectModel(object);
```

Which could also be done by parameters instead of just objects -

```
function objectModel(name, description) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.Description = ko.observable(description);
}

var john = new objectModel('John', 'a person');
```

Comment: Hi PW Kad, did you find time to see my comment to beauXjames solution above? Any idea?

Comment: I don't understand the problem - have you looked at the mapping utility?

Answer (score 0):

Surely, the best way to map one object over to another is through knockout's utility function, arrayMap...for example, if you've got your array object...

```
var thisArray = [ 
    { property: 'Email', value: 'name@email.com'}, 
    { property: '', value: ''}... 
];
```

and you've got some other object type you're mapping to...

```
var newObject = function(email) { 
    var self = this;
    self.Email = email;
};
```

it's as simple as...

```
ko.utils.arrayMap(thisArray, function(arrayItem) { 
    if(arrayItem.property === 'Email')
        return new newObject(arrayItem.value);
});
```

Which returns a new array of newObject.

Comment: whatif the signature of newObject takes in multiple arguments and not one which in your case is Email, i though agree with PW Kad's solution but still i have to individually find which property is a Name or Email and then construct the object....

Comment: well, depends. are these multiple arguments something you can put into your 'arrayItem'? If not, then you'd need to put them somewhere, right? You can always write a custom mapping routine with the ko.mapping plug in...there are more topics on SO for that as well.