# Knockout observable variable not changing its value on click

Tags: knockout.js

I don't know why my `currentTitle` is not changing on click.

```
viewModel = {
    articles: ko.observableArray([{
        id: 1,
        title: "Article One",
        content: "Content for article one."},
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Article Two",
        content: "Content for article two."},
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Article Three",
        content: "Content for article three."}
                                               ]),
    currentTitle: ko.observable("old")
};


<div data-bind="foreach: viewModel.articles()">
<div data-bind="text:title,click: getTitle"></div>
</div>
<div data-bind="text: viewModel.currentTitle"></div>


getTitle = function(){
        viewModel.currentTitle = "title";
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Posted my code here : http://jsfiddle.net/devnegikec/TBP43/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting value of Observable not updating in Knockout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391415/setting-value-of-observable-not-updating-in-knockout)

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted if you are happy with it and it adequately answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getTitle` function updates the value of currentTitle rather than updating the observable.

Try:

```
getTitle = function(){
    viewModel.currentTitle("title");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @phuzi said, you're not updating the observable correctly, but you also need to pass the selected item to the function too:

```
getTitle = function(item){
    viewModel.currentTitle(item.title);
}
```

See here: [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TBP43/2/)

Comment: @Devnegikec you can mark the answer by clicking the tick if you're happy with the answer

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/TBP43/3/

Changed:
getTitle to setTitle.

Included setTitle in viewmodel.

Removed unnecessary 'viewmodel.' in binding.

I would recommend having a 'chosenArticle' in the viewmodel and simply binding the text with

```
   text: chosenArticle.title
```

PS: Please remove the jquery tag