# Knockout cloning does not work with function instances

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, reference, clone, ko.observablearray

Basically what I read and what I used thus far for cloning an array without any references in between is something like this:

`var clonedArray = ko.observableArray(originalArray().slice(0));`

But in this following **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/c729c/)** it does not seem to work:

```
var field = function(settings){
  var _self = this;
    _self.Id = settings.Id;
    _self.Flag = ko.observable(settings.Flag);
    return _self;
};

var viewModel = function(){
 var _vm = this;

    _vm.fields = ko.observableArray([
        new field({Id: 1, Flag: true}),
        new field({Id: 2, Flag: false})
    ]);

    _vm.fieldsCloned = ko.observableArray(_vm.fields().slice(0));

    return _vm;
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: You created a _shallow_ clone of an array. So each array contains the same references to the objects the original array was referring to. I suppose you wanted to make a deep clone...

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes you're correct. I updated my question to include answer.

Comment: No don't do that, if you have an answer to your question, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

Reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7001501/593958)

> I was faced with the same task; to clone an observable array. The only
>   why I could figure out how to do it, is to convert the observable to
>   an JS object, then convert that object to an observable object. The
>   following function requires KnockoutJS mapping plugin:
>   http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

```
function cloneObservable(observableObject) {
    return ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(observableObject));
}
```